# while loop doesn't re-execute after continue

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm creating a blackjack game in which i have to take users bet and insure that it is not more then there total and then return user bet.  I've tried this code but it doesn't seems to be working, while loop doesn't re-execute after continue.

```
def take_bet(total):
    while True:
        x = int(input('plz : '))
        while True :
            if x <= total :
            break
        if x > total :
            print(f"your bet is higher then your total {total} .")
            continue
        else:
            break
        
    return x
```

Comment: The whole ```if...else``` block is outside ```while``` loop. It is executed after ```while``` loop is broken

Comment: Your inner `while True` loop never changes `x` or `total`, so it will be an infinite loop if the condition is false.

Comment: first while loop should re-exicute after continue right ?

Comment: The `continue` statement isn't inside any of the loops, so there's nothing for it to continue

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your indentation errors prevent the code from running.  Your supposed loop `continue` statement is not inside any loop.  Most of all, your code merely defines a function that you never call.

Comment: `if x <= total : break` is not properly indented. You need to provide a [mre], also including input, expected output, and actual output. **Edit**: Also include the function call.

Comment: You should get syntax errors from this. So I suspect you didn't copy the indentation correctly.

Comment: The code is still problematic after edit. `if x <= total` block has no statement under it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if statement needs to be inside your loop:

```
def take_bet(total):
    while True:
        x = int(input('plz : '))
        if x > total :
            print(f"your bet is higher then your total {total} .")
        else:
            break
    return x
```

You do not need any of the other loops or if/else checks

Comment: Thank's bro it worked . there was just a little problem i had to add break statement after if in while loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single while loop to take care of everything as shown below.

```py
def take_bet(total):

    bet = int(input('plz : '))  #Initialise bet.

    while bet > total :
        print(f"your bet is higher then your total {total} .")
        bet = int(input('plz : ')) #Ask again for an allowed bet.

    return bet
```

No need for the added complexity of if statements and breaks.